# Get body from request in RXJS retryWhen

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a Http observable that works as a wrapper around fetch. This wrapper handles tasks as authentication, ratelimit, etc. I'm trying to implement the retryWhen method to handle http errors, and in case of a 401 requesting new tokens and retry it.

When there is a http error, our REST api sends an error response with in the body an object with more error information. I want that body inside the .catch of the subscription, but only thing I get is an Promise. But I only want the body, because I don't want to check of error is a promise.

```
return this.#addRequest(request, options.disableBatch).pipe(
  retryWhen(errors => {
    return errors.pipe(
      mergeMap((response: globalThis.Response) => {
        if (response.status === 401) {
          this.tokenStatus.next('invalid')
          return this.tokenStatus.pipe(
            filter((state) => state === 'valid'), 
            take(1),
          )
        }
        return throwError(() => response.json()) <-- response with Promise
      })
    )
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the promise to resolve before you throw the error.  Below are two ways you can accomplish this.

```
mergeMap((response: globalThis.Response) => {
  if (repsonse.status === 401) { /* ... */ }
  // Either of the lines below will produce a similar result.
  return response.json().then(x => { throw new Error(x); });
  return from(response.json()).pipe(switchMap(x => throwError(() => new Error(x))));
})
```

IMO, the first method is preferable:

- You don't have to wrap a promise in **from** to return it from inside a flattening operator.  I see this a lot and it is unnecessary since rxjs treats promises like observables.
- You don't have to use the **throwError** operator, rxjs will pick up on thrown errors in most cases.